# Merge .rdata and .data sections into text section

Tags: c++, visual-studio, llvm

I have a program where I execute C++ code at run time, like in JIT. The program when run, creates C++ code on the fly, converts to LLVM IR and obj using LLVM. It then loads the text section and runs it. The programs runs fine when there is just one text section. I wanted to know how I can run it when there are .data/.rdata sections. Visual Studio linker has /MERGE when can merge .rdata to .text. How can I implement this - so that I can merge the sections in obj to just one text section?

Comment: I don't follow you: you have additional rdata/data sections not referenced by your obj file?

Comment: The obj code has .rdata .data and .text sections. I want to merge .rdata/.data into .text so that I can load .text in memory and execute them.

Comment: That would require re-compile the code almost from scratch: you don't control where global or read-only data is put, the compiler does. On a Windows environment you would likely get away with your own "loader-like" section mapping although that requires some PE internals. Not sure if this could be accomplished though..

Comment: Compiling to native code in runtime? Sounds to me like one giant vulnerability. Would you like to explain how you are going to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `/MERGE` option in Visual Studio.

> The /MERGE option combines the first section (from) with the second section (to), naming the resulting section to. For example, /merge:.rdata=.text.
>   If the second section does not exist, LINK renames the section from as to.
>   The /MERGE option is useful for creating VxDs and overriding the compiler-generated section names.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxz26dz2.aspx